# Echo Multiple Database Results?

Tags: php

I'm sure there's an easy way to do it, but I'm not finding the solution via the Goog (and on here), but in the following code, I want it to render all the matches in the database, but it only matches one via the echo line below ("title" is available for "checkout" on separate lines).  Any idea how I can get this to work?

```
$conn->Open($connString);
$searchquery = $_GET ['search'];
$selectCommand="SELECT * FROM AuthorTitle WHERE  title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR author LIKE '%$searchquery%'";

if(isset($_GET['search'])){
$rs = $conn->Execute($selectCommand);

//opens a recordset from the connection object

if (!$rs->EOF){

$selectCommand=$rs->Fields("ProductID");
$author=$rs->Fields("author");
$title=$rs->Fields("title");

echo "<h2>Search Result for '<b>$searchquery</b>':</h2>
<p><b>$title</b>, $author is available for checkout.</p><br />";

}

else

print "No results found.<br /><br />";



$rs->Close;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're going to have to post more code than that. For instance, what is `$rs`?

Comment: you should check if `$_GET['search']` isset before assigning it to `$searchquery`

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability... enjoy having your site pwn3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your resultset

```
while (!$rs->EOF){ 
    //echo here , then move to the next row
    $rs->movenext();
}
```

EDIT:

```
//opens a recordset from the connection object
if ($rs->EOF){
    print "No results found.<br /><br />";
}else{
    while (!$rs->EOF){ 
        $selectCommand=$rs->Fields("ProductID");
        $author=$rs->Fields("author");
        $title=$rs->Fields("title");

        echo "<h2>Search Result for '<b>$searchquery</b>':</h2>
        <p><b>$title</b>, $author is available for checkout.</p><br />";

        $rs->movenext();
    }
}

//close at the end
$rs->Close;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! How would I keep the error message (No results found) in the original if/else loop?